# C# Generics Efficiency, a better way to do this

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Ok, lets say I have classes such as the following:

```
public class KPIObject<T> //<--This class where T is the following classes
{
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class KPICycleCountAccuracyData //<--There are 20 of these with different names and values
{
    public string Facility { get; set; }
    public string CCAdjustedCases { get; set; }
    public string TotalCases { get; set; }
    public string CCAdjustedPercent { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have:

```
public List<ReportData>> ProcessAccountReport(GetAccountReport request)
{
    var data = new List<ReportData>();
    ProcessKPI(data, request.KPICycleCountAccuracy, "KPICycleCountAccuracy"); //<-- 20 of these
    return data;
}
```

Here is the ProcessKPI method:

```
private static void ProcessKPI<T>(List<ReportData> data, ICollection<KPIObject<T>> items, string name)
{
    if (items == null || items.Count <= 0) return;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.Data == null || item.Data.Count <= 0) continue;
        var temp = new List<object>();
        temp.AddRange((IEnumerable<object>)item.Data);
        data.Add(new ReportData { Data = temp, Name = name, Title = item.Caption });
    }
}
```

All of this works and compiles correctly, I am just wondering if this is the most efficient way of doing this.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I changed process KPI to this:

```
private static void ProcessKPI<T>(ICollection<ReportData> data, ICollection<KPIObject<T>> items, string name)
        {
            if (items == null || items.Count <= 0) return;
            foreach (var item in items.Where(item => item.Data != null && item.Data.Count > 0))
            {
                data.Add(new ReportData { Data = (IEnumerable<object>)item.Data, Name = name, Title = item.Caption });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to be clear what type of efficiency gain you are looking for: are you saying that you are making 20 calls to `ProcessKPI()` (one call for each of the 20 types you indicated in the first code snippet), and that if you added one more type you would have to add one more call to `ProcessKPI()`, etc.? And you are looking for a more scalable way to write this code?

Comment: Performance, less code, memory issues.  Yes, if I add another class, I have to make another ProcessKPI call.

Comment: Not sure about the long of it, but I do know your data parameter doesn't need to be a ref since it's not a value type.

Comment: Ok, I removed ref and changed the IEnumerable position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of comments

- There is no need to make `data` a `ref` parameter in `ProcessKPI`.  A `ref` parameter is only meaningful for a `class` type in C# if you actually assign to it.  Here you're just modifying the object so `ref` doesn't by you anything except awkward call syntax
- Even though `Count` is signed it won't ever return a negative value.
- I would prefer `(IEnumerable<object>)item.Data` over the `as IEnumerable<object>` version. If the latter fails it will result in an `ArgumentNullException` when really it's a casting issue.

Comment: I removed ref and changed the IEnumerable placement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Speed**
Assuming you are talking about computational efficiency (i.e. speed), there are two operations that you might be able to improve:

First, you create a copy of the `item.Data` in the `temp` variable. When you know that the resulting `ReportData` will never be modified, you may use the item.Data directly, forgoing the expensive copy operation.

`data.Add(new ReportData {
   Data = (IEnumerable<object>)item.Data, 
   Name = name,
   Title = item.Caption });`

Second, converting to `IEnumerable<object>` will probably cause unnecessary boxing/unboxing at a later point. See if it makes sense for your application to add a generic type parameter to `ReportData`, so you may instantiate it as `new ReportData<KPIObject>()`. That way the compiler may do a better job of optimizing the code.

**Memory**
By implementing your solution using continuations you may be able to process one ReportData element at a time instead of all at once, thereby reducing the memory footprint. Have a look at the [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) statement to see how to impelement such an approach.

**Other**
For futher code quality improvements, JaredPar's answer offers some exellent advice.

Comment: I think you're mistaken, I don't see any copying whatsoever in this method. The list operations are all references, and the string copies are all references. So at most he's copying some pointer addresses. Also I believe your statements about boxing are unjustified unless the OP is working with List<int> etc, there is no boxing occurring when the types are reference types. -1 for this, +1 for the yield information

Comment: @ChrisMarisic AddRange() indeed copies all references, not the complete objects. I did not mean to imply that all strings are copied. But it's still those 20 references that have to be copied in each iteration; references that may live in a discontiguous stretch of memory depending on the implementation of List<T>. It's cost may be small, but leaving out AddRange()'s copy operation is definitely faster than leaving it in.